# How to work with a lot of directory & element strings?

Tags: python

I have a python class which uses selenium, takes and opens a web path. I am trying to find a way to make a list of the full `XPath` or Element ID's in a separate file (`txt` or `json` or whatever you believe is best) to store all thge elementids in, then the it will take the the file and link it, for example the following `XPath` will be as:

```
XPath1='/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[''1]/tbody/tr/td/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input'
```

My code will then look in this file, take the path and assign it to the variable. But what is the best way to store all these paths and ID's. I am sure that storing 30/40 these in script inst good etticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our product, we store the paths in a separate python module as enums. It takes away the need to write code for parsing txt or JSON files. You can just import this module and use each of the paths as a variable in your code. Also, we can store paths in python class, if there are not many. If choosing between txt or json, json is preferable for me, again due to ease of use.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Super useful to know!! Can i ask if you just write it in a .py file? Declaring all the links? then i guess you call the variables?

Comment: Yes, for example, you declaring links as xpath1 = 'string_path'' and then you can use this as just variable xpath1. Of course, you need to import this module in your code.